# How to upload image via stream in SocketIO [iOS]

Tags: ios, socket.io

So this is what my backend code looks like

```
 socket.on('uploadimage', function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   stream = ss.createStream();
   ss(socket).emit('file', stream);
   stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('uploadedfile.png'));
 });
```

I want to catch the backend stream`(ss(socket))` , in my native application(iOS) so that i can write the image data on it.

I am using [SocketIO](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) iOS client.
Is there any option to access the ss(socket) stream in the iOS native client side of the application? I want to use it for image/video upload. All I am getting option for emitting the whole data at once, which I think will not be a good option for sending large file.

Comment: did you found  a solution?

Comment: I do have the same question. Please let us know